# How to use GL_TRIANGLE_FAN to draw a circle in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

Seasons Greetings everyone! I adapted the code from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDCSKlFqpaU) to support using a VAO/VBO, but now I get this:

[image: weirdest circle ever]

Instead of a nice round circle. Here's the code:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC

#include <GLEW/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <corecrt_math_defines.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 3000
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 1900

void drawPolygon(GLuint& vao, GLuint& vbo, GLfloat x,
    GLfloat y, GLdouble radius, GLint numberOfSides);

int main(void) {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        return -1;
    }

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();
    glGetError();

    glViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    GLuint vao, vbo;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 0, SCREEN_HEIGHT, -1, 1);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        drawPolygon(vao, vbo, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2,
            SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, 250.0f, 50);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void drawPolygon(GLuint& vao, GLuint& vbo, GLfloat x,
    GLfloat y, GLdouble radius, GLint numberOfSides) {
    int numVertices = numberOfSides + 2;

    GLdouble twicePi = 2.0f * M_PI;

    vector<GLdouble> circleVerticesX;
    vector<GLdouble> circleVerticesY;

    circleVerticesX.push_back(x);
    circleVerticesY.push_back(y);

    for (int i = 1; i < numVertices; i++) {
        circleVerticesX.push_back(x + (radius *
            cos(i * twicePi / numberOfSides)));
        circleVerticesY.push_back(y + (radius *
            sin(i * twicePi / numberOfSides)));
    }

    vector<GLdouble> vertices;
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
        vertices.push_back(circleVerticesX[i]);
        vertices.push_back(circleVerticesY[i]);
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numVertices * sizeof(
        GLdouble), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_DOUBLE, GL_FALSE,
        2 * sizeof(GLdouble), (void*)0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 27);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

What the heck have I done wrong?! Using [the original code](https://github.com/SonarSystems/OpenGL-Tutorials/blob/master/Drawing%20A%20Circle%20Using%20A%20Triangle%20Fan/main.cpp) works, so I am absolutely baffled by this ridiculous result! MTIA to anyone who can help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of your VBO is `numVertices * sizeof(GLdouble)`, which is half the actual size of your vertex data (there is an x *and* a y component for each vertex). Thus, you end up drawing twice as many vertices as your VBO actually has vertex data for. Reading out of bounds of your VBO seems to result in just zeroes in your OpenGL implementation, which is why all vertices of the lower half of your circle are just the bottom left corner (this is not guaranteed unless you explicitly enable robust buffer access, just what your driver and GPU seem to be doing anyways)…

couple of notes:

- You generally don't want to use `double` unless you need it. `double` takes twice the memory bandwidth, and arithmetic on `double` is generally at least a bit slower than `float` (yes, even on an x86 CPU since floating point arithmetic is not really done using the x87 FPU anymore nowadays). GPUs in particular are built for `float` arithmetic. Especially on consumer GPUs, `double` arithmetic is *significantly* (an order of magnitude) slower than `float`.
- Why not simply push the vertex data directly into `vertices` rather than first into `circleVerticesX` and `circleVerticesY` and then copying it over into `vertices` from there?
- You know exactly how many vertices are going to be generated. Thus, there's no need to dynamically grow your vertex container in the loop that generates the coordinates (among other things, the `.push_back()` will almost certainly prevent vectorization of the loop). I would suggest to at least `.reserve()` the corresponding number of elements (assuming this is an `std::vector`) before entering the loop. Personally, I would just allocate an array of the appropriate, fixed size via

  ```
  auto vertex_data = std::unique_ptr<GLfloat[]> { new GLfloat[numVertices * 2] };
  ```

  in this case.
- You don't actually need a center point. Since a circle is a convex shape, you can simply use one of the points on the circle as the central vertex of your fan.
- This is not necessarily the most efficient way to draw a circle (a lot of long, thin triangles; more on that [here](http://www.humus.name/index.php?page=News&ID=228))
- You probably don't want to generate and upload your vertex data again and again every frame unless something about it changes.
- Apart from that, you will probably want to make your `glDrawArrays` call draw the actual number of vertices rather than just always `27`…

Comment: Wow, what a great answer! Thank you so much Michael, and Merry Christmas mate :D P.S. Yes I'm aware of the stupidity of filling three arrays instead of one, but that's how the tute does it so I just blindly copied that code. I also realise that using double is wasteful of memory and GPU cycles, but thought that might fix my problem since I could see that the values returned by `cos()` and `sin()` on floats were inaccurate. And I was originally using `GLfloat* vertices = new GLfloat[numVertices]` to create the arrays, but vectors are easier to inspect in the debugger ;-) Anyway thanks again! :D

Comment: I tried implementing your suggestion re: using a smart pointer instead of a vector, but now I get a weird squished shape instead of a regular n-sided polygon. If I keep using a vector, I get what I expect. Can you please explain why? I'd like to use a smart pointer as you suggested if I could make it work...

Comment: Here's a picture illustrating my above comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/qcHJi9U1BxHxsV258. That's supposed to be a regular pentagon.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out :-) Up until today I thought I was a reasonably-good C++ programmer, but now I feel like I should go back to Programming 101 classes LOL. Thanks again mate and best wishes for the new year!